# Optimization problem in Matlab

Tags: optimization, matlab

I think **Optimization toolbox** might be helpful, but I am not sure about which method I should use.

I am trying to update the value of $\phi$ (a matrix), given all the other variables, matrices and operators:
[image]

I think differentiation might not be suitable in my case, since H is an operator rather than a variable. The one below is same as the one above but in linear step from. It's actually quite hard to solve for $H^{T}H$.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create a vector $x$ and then based on this vector create a vector for your function. Then use the built in min function. The size of the interval of vector $x$ should be chosen carefully

Comment: The method to be used depends on function $f$. You have told us nothing about $f$.

Comment: The min function provides the index of the vector where the function is minimum. So from this you can know what value minimize your function

Comment: Do you know that the method you use is called Levenberg-Marquardt Method ?
 (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Levenberg-MarquardtMethod.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your function look like? If it is simple enough you can use the symbolic toolbox to differentiate your function with respect to x with the diff(f(x),x) command and than use the solve(f'(x),x) command to get the extreme point(s).

If you apply diff(diff(f(x),x),x) and than insert the extreme point(s) you can check whether its a minimum or maximum...Also make sure to check the asymptotic behavior of your function to find out whether your points are global or local extreme points.

Edit: Ok I just saw you edited your post and wrote down the function, you can't use my method for this.